Any way to wrapped all axios requests within InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions()?
I've tried
const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use((cfg) => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    const token = getToken();
    if (token) {
      cfg.headers.Authorization = `${token.scheme} ${token.value}`;
    }
    return cfg;
  });
});

Which of course axios isn't happy, it's not returning anything. Any way to do runAfterInteractions synchronously?
Or any ideas other wrapping each api calls manually (there's a lot of them)?
